# How to extend mask region (True) by 1 or 2 pixels?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, mask

I have a numpy mask of True and False values, detecting black regions  in an image.

I want to extend the True regions by 1 or 2 pixel.

For example, considering this mask:

```html
[[False False False False False]
 [False False TRUE  False False]
 [False TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  False]
 [False False TRUE  False False]
 [False False False False False]
```

I want to have:

```html
[[False False TRUE  False False]
 [False TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  False]
 [TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE ]
 [False TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  False]
 [False False TRUE  False False]
```

Actually I could have made a for loop, but in a big image it's to slow.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try morphology dilation operation using an elliptical kernel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dilation is the easiest way to extend the "True" regions.

Consider the array:

```
a = np.array([[False, False, False, False, False],
              [False, False,  True, False, False],
              [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
              [False, False,  True, False, False],
              [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

Convert to integer data type

```
a = a.astype(np.uint8)
```

You get:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Perform dilation using ellipse kernel of size 3x3:

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(a, kernel, iterations=1)
```

`dilate`:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Convert the result to boolean data type:

```
d = np.array(dilate, dtype=bool)
```

Resulting array:

```
array([[False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False]])
```

To extend the `True` regions further:

- increase the kernel size
- repeat dilation operation using `iteration`

***Note:*** Boolean array cannot be used as input with `cv2.dilate()`, or else it throws `error: (-5:Bad argument)`. Hence we convert it to `int` data type, perform the opertion and convert it back to `bool` data type.

It seems

Answer (score 0):

You can use the boolean sum:

```
new_mask = mask.copy()
new_mask[:,1:] = mask[:,1:]+mask[:,:-1]
new_mask[1:,:] = new_mask[1:,:]+mask[:-1,:]
```

`new_mask` now is:

```
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False]])
```

the sum between two boolean works as a logical or, so in the previous lines of code you are saying: `new_mask[i,j] = (mask[i,j] or mask[i,j-1] or mask[i-1,j])`